# Difference between a .csv and a .txt file

Tags: c#, csv

What is the difference between these two file format.

i found this from [Here](http://www.tezimandee.com/forum/topic/2159-difference-between-a-csv-and-a-txt-file/)

**.txt File:**
This is a plain text file which can be opened using a notepad present on all desktop PCs running MS Windows any version. You can store any type of text in this file. There is no limitation of what so ever text format. Due to ease of use for end users many daily data summery providers use .txt files. These files contain data which is properly comma seperated.

**.csv File: abreviation of "comma seperated values"**
This is a special file extension commonly used by MS Excel. Basically this is also a plain text file but with a limitation of comma seperated values. Normally when you double click this type of file it will open in MS Excel. If you do not have MS Excel installed on your computer or you find Notepad easy to use then you also can open this file in a notepad by right clicking the file and from the menu select "Open With" and then choose notepad.

**My Question :**

- what does means comma seperated value?
- if i'm going to create .csv file using c#, does i need to write file using `StreamWriter` and does it need to only change the the extention to .csv?
- if so do i need to change the writing string with commas?

thanx....

Comment: A file with comma delimited values can be also be separated by commas. Apps like Excel convert it implicitly.

Comment: CSV is a convention-based text files which well known and recognized. The main use of it is for tabular data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what does means comma seperated value?

Values separated by Comma, for example.

```
Name,Id,3,Address
```

> if i'm going to create .csv file using c#, does i need to write file
>   using StreamWriter and does it need to only change the the extention
>   to .csv?

Changing extension of the file will help you in opening it in MS Excel, other than that it can be anything and you can still open it through your code `(StreamReader)`

> if so do i need to change the writing string with commas?

Yes, separate your values with `Comma`, or you can use any other delimiter you like. It can be semicolon `;` as well since `,` in some languages/cultures is used for decimal separator.

Comment: Actually, there shouldn't be a space after the comma. Otherwise it becomes part of the value.

Comment: that means instead of '\t' i need to put ','. ?

Comment: @TilT, you can use `\t` as delimiter, but then technically it would be : [Delimiter-separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values) (DSV)

Comment: @Habib no it would still be a CSV, technically and actually. More specifically, it would be a CSV subset, TSV. DSV is entirely different and is [Linux' counterpart to CSV](https://web.archive.org/web/20191026160302/http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch05s02.html#id2901882) and uses a different escaping method. DSV is supposedly superior to CSV. Both DSV and CSV can use different delimiters (tabs, commas, etc).

Answer (score 4):

CSV is structured like this:

"value","value1,"value2"

A text file can be anything from delimited, to free form , fixed width, jagged right, etc...

CSV files can be a pain in the ass if you have commas in your data, and don't properly qualify the values.

I typically create tab delimited or pipe delimited files.

Comment: If you quote values you can have commas, quotes or even line breaks in them. Where is the PITA there?

Comment: When you get a file from an iSeries for example, they only quote strings. Numeric values are not quoted. It's doable, but if you're like the OP and asking what is a csv file, parsing an inconsistent qualified file is going to be a challenge. Also if you're dealing with data that has ' " for feet and inches, now you're dealing with embeded qualifiers.

Comment: I just had my boss ask which is the best format to use when storing comma seperated values in a .txt or .csv. We use the text file to create a comma seperated file. We create the file in a mainframe program like natural or cobol and then use fileAid to download to the PC world. Then at this point i normally rename the file myFile.file to myFile.txt and then open EXCEL and then upload the file as a text format and then go through and go through the steps telling it that it is a comma seperated file and setting the fields to how I want them (text, date, currency, etc...) Is this the best way?

Answer (score 3):

From the perspective of programming, file extensions do not make a difference. In fact you may write comma seperated values inside a txt file.

Comma seperated values indicates the values are just seperated with commas; this is helpful if you want to store some data and share it accross multiple systems (on the otherhand XML is a better option).

Assume you need to store name, age and location;

```
TilT,25,Germany
```

is a comma seperated data.

In the scope of c#, you need to add commas between your values and you may save it as a CSV file or a TXT file; it makes no difference.

Comment: @Joey may or may not; in general you do not use spaces, but if you are writing a program to parse it, it does not make much difference.

Comment: Erm, in CSV spaces after the comma are part of the value. This has nothing to do with who reads or parses it.

Comment: @Joey I assume that user tries to create and/or parse an CSV file with c#. I do not know whether a general format of a CSV file which does not allow spaces after commas. But you are right in the context that not using spaces is a general convention. I have updated the answer; thanks for remark.

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt :-) Most proper CSV implementations follow that.

Comment: @Joey thanks; "Spaces are considered part
       of a field and should not be ignored."